# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false when external login is used

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication

this worked but suddenly it stopped working.

I have this code in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Audience"],
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Key"] ?? string.Empty))
        };
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Google:ClientId"] ?? string.Empty;
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Google:ClientSecret"] ?? string.Empty;
        googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/Security/GoogleSignIn";
    });
```

And this is the callback when external login returns:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string? returnUrl = null, string? remoteError = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new ()
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList()
    };

    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        ModelState
            .AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error desde el proveedor externo: {remoteError}");

        loginViewModel.SetError(remoteError);

        return View("Login", loginViewModel);
    }

    // Get the login information about the user from the external login provider
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        ModelState
            .AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error al cargar la información del login externo.");

        loginViewModel.SetError("Error al cargar la información del login externo.");

        return View("Login", loginViewModel);
    }

    // If the user already has a login (i.e if there is a record in AspNetUserLogins
    // table) then sign-in the user with this external login provider
    var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

    var userName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

    if (signInResult.Succeeded)
    {
        if (userName != null)
        {
            await SetLastLoggedOnTime(userName);
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            if (user != null)
                await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
        }

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        // Verifica que el usuario exista. Si existe, agrega el login y autentica
        var creado = userName == null ? null : await _usuarioService.CreateUserFromExternal(userName, info);
        if (creado != null)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(creado, isPersistent: false);
            if (userName != null)
                await SetLastLoggedOnTime(userName);

            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            loginViewModel.Notification = new Integration.ViewModels.MessageViewModel
            {
                Type = Integration.ViewModels.AlertTypes.Danger
            };
            if (signInResult.IsLockedOut)
                loginViewModel.SetError("El usuario está bloqueado.");
            else if (signInResult.IsNotAllowed)
                loginViewModel.SetError("El usuario no está autorizado para ingresar.");
            else
                loginViewModel.SetError("El usuario no está registrado en la plataforma.");
        }
    }

    return View("Login", loginViewModel);
}
```

After that, the last redirect sends the user to a secured page. When that secure page is loaded, the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false, causing the brower to be redirected again to login page.

Then, I manually change the browser URL to point to the same secured page, and in that case `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true, loading the corresponding page.

What could happen here?

If I use normal login, entering username and password, it works at first login.

EDIT:

When debugging, this is what I get:

[image]

When succedded I do a `LocalRedirect` to the private page:

[image]

Cookie authentication is used, and in fact, as I said, normal login does work. And middle is the same I have used before, added in `Startup.cs` file.

Cheers

Jaime

Comment: Well, accordingly to your description, It seems like your external login process is encountering issues with authentication persistence, causing `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to be false after the redirect to a secured page. Check the middleware order in program.cs to ensure authentication middleware is set up before other middleware. Verify that cookie authentication, if used alongside external logins, is configured correctly to set cookies upon successful login.  May I know which version on .NET are you using?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I have updated the question with a debugging session.